# How to keep the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox open even after the user presses the OK button?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# programming. Currently, I am using the following code to get a user input and after the user types inside the text box and presses Ok, the whole input box closes. The user has to run the program every time to get the inputbox. How to keep the input box always open? This is a C# program and I have used a Microsoft.VisualBasic reference for the code to run.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Text
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please Type In The Number", "Type");

      if (input == "")
        {
        }
        bool valid = false;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it in a loop of some sort. The way an input box works is that it opens gets user input closes and passes along the data entered. What I think you want is to have it reopen every time the user hits okay

Try this code and it should be similar to what you want

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Text
 {
 class Program
 {
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     //create variable
     bool valid = false;
     //start loop
     //when ever the valid boolean evaluates as false the loop continues
     // when its true it will kick out of the loop
     while(valid == false)
     {
         \\create input box and store variable
         string input = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please Type In The Number", "Type");

         \\check if variable is 'exit' if it is set boolean to true
         if (input == "exit")
         {
              valid = true;
         }
         \\otherwise its false and the loop will continue
         else
         {
              valid = false
         }
      }
   }
 }
 }
```

This code creates a simple while loop that terminates when the user enters exit into the input box